# Flutter web app : open url in the default smartphone browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, url-launcher

I have a firebase dynamic link that can be share in social media like facebook

in some cases when user click on the dynamic link from Facebook app ( example the link is my flutter web app : https://mydomain.app ) this link will be open inside the **Facebook browser** ( default behavior ) so it's ok

now inside the **Facebook browser** I have the home page of my flutter web app with button 'start' to navigate to page1 for example ( https://mydomain.app/page1 ) . So what I want to do is :

- when user click on 'start' button the new page ( page1 ) should be open in the d**efault browser** ( **safari or chrome** ) rather then the current **facebook browser**

***Note :*** I have try with **url_launcher** and **html.window.open('https://mydomain.app/page1', '_self')** but still new page ( page1 ) is open in **Facebook browser**, any idea how I can launch page1 url in the **default smartphone browser** rather then the current **Facebook browser** ?